# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library

Tags: python, django, docker, gis, postgis

I'm trying to use `gis` in the `docker`:

This is `Dockerfile` of django:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk update \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
  && apk add postgresql-dev \
  # Pillow dependencies
  && apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev lcms2-dev openjpeg-dev tiff-dev tk-dev tcl-dev \
  # CFFI dependencies
  && apk add libffi-dev py-cffi \
  # Translations dependencies
  && apk add gettext \
  # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dbshell
  && apk add postgresql-client


# ADD PostGIS here
# POSTGIS dependencies
ENV POSTGIS_VERSION 2.4.4
ENV POSTGIS_SHA256 0dff4902556ad45430e2b85dbe7e9baa758c6eb0bfd5ff6948f478beddd56b67


RUN set -ex \
    \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .fetch-deps \
        ca-certificates \
        openssl \
        tar \
    \
    && wget -O postgis.tar.gz "https://github.com/postgis/postgis/archive/$POSTGIS_VERSION.tar.gz" \
    && echo "$POSTGIS_SHA256 *postgis.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c - \
    && mkdir -p /usr/src/postgis \
    && tar \
        --extract \
        --file postgis.tar.gz \
        --directory /usr/src/postgis \
        --strip-components 1 \
    && rm postgis.tar.gz \
    \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        autoconf \
        automake \
        g++ \
        json-c-dev \
        libtool \
        libxml2-dev \
        make \
        perl \
    \
    # add libcrypto from (edge:main) for gdal-2.3.0
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .crypto-rundeps \
        --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main \
        libressl2.7-libcrypto \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps-testing \
        --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing \
        gdal-dev \
        geos-dev \
        proj4-dev \
        protobuf-c-dev \
    && cd /usr/src/postgis \
    && ./autogen.sh \
# configure options taken from:
# https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-grass/postgis.git/tree/debian/rules?h=jessie
    && ./configure \
#       --with-gui \
    && make \
    && make install \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .postgis-rundeps \
        json-c \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .postgis-rundeps-testing \
        --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing \
        geos \
        gdal \
        py-gdal \
        proj4 \
        protobuf-c \
    && cd / \
    && rm -rf /usr/src/postgis \
    && apk del .fetch-deps .build-deps .build-deps-testing
#  && apk del .fetch-deps .build-deps .build-deps-testing
# END POSTGIS Changes


# Requirements are installed here to ensure they will be cached.
COPY ./requirements /requirements
RUN pip install -r /requirements/local.txt

COPY ./compose/production/django/entrypoint /entrypoint
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint

COPY ./compose/local/django/start /start
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /start
RUN chmod +x /start

COPY ./compose/local/django/celery/worker/start /start-celeryworker
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /start-celeryworker
RUN chmod +x /start-celeryworker

COPY ./compose/local/django/celery/beat/start /start-celerybeat
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /start-celerybeat
RUN chmod +x /start-celerybeat

COPY ./compose/local/django/celery/flower/start /start-flower
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /start-flower
RUN chmod +x /start-flower

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint"]
```

This is my `Dockerfile` of postgres:

```
FROM mdillon/postgis 

COPY ./compose/production/postgres/maintenance /usr/local/bin/maintenance
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/maintenance/*
RUN mv /usr/local/bin/maintenance/* /usr/local/bin \
    && rmdir /usr/local/bin/maintenance
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was only necessary to remove this line of `Dockerfile`:     `&& apk del .fetch-deps .build-deps .build-deps-testing`

I have not figured it out yet, but most likely it removes all the packages I added above.

Comment: I think it's because you delete the development packages ".build-deps-testing". I would imagine that one or more of them are needed by django to hook into the libraries

Comment: @SuneKjærgård is right, django will need to call the gdal executable and you shouldn't delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but by reading the debian package section, it does not look like you're installing `gdal-dev` or `libgdal-dev`, the name depends on your distribution but you get the idea.

Comment: Most likely, the analogue of libgdal-dev is https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/x86/gdal-dev